# Logitech Mouse and Keyboard Click Issues

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, mouse, logitech

I have a Logitech K360 Keyboard and K325 Mouse on my Ubuntu 12.04 desktop. These had been working out of the box for a while, but recently they started acting up. For example, if I open up Chrome, the mouse and keyboard suddenly stop working. I can still move the cursor, it just won't click on anything. Also <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (to switch applications) on my keyboard stops working. I downloaded Solar thinking maybe putting both devices on one Unifying Receiver would help, but same thing. Does anyone have any ideas?

Before you point me to the direction of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128345/logitech-m515-does-not-work-after-upgrade-to-12-04), I have already tried this, plus my mouse is being recognized, just not behaving properly.

Thanks in advance.

p.s. I have no idea why this would matter, but I recently put `transmission-gtk --minimized` as a startup application. The mouse and keyboard really started acting up then.

Comment: reinstall the driver: `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-all && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all`

Comment: @Mike B did you try this and did it work?

Comment: @JohnnyBizzle, this did not work.

Comment: I think the fact that hardware manufacturers build stuff for Windoze means we sometimes get bitten in the backside. I am having similar problems with my Logitech mouse and Alt+Tab not happening. Try using [special key]+[s] to task switch instead. I wonder if it is just Logitech mice causing problems?

Comment: I've tried another mouse (non Logitech) and that works fine. Perhaps the wires in the mouse cable are frayed?