# Logitech Performance MX mouse shows as "unknown" in Power Statistics

Tags: 16.04, mouse, indicator, battery, logitech-unifying

My Logitech Unifying Receiver with wireless K800 illuminated keyboard and wireless Performance MX mouse work flawlessly in both Windows and Linux out of the box. In Windows you can install optional drivers for scroll wheel enhancements and a nicer volume meter display as a consequence. In Linux/Ubuntu there are no optional drivers you can download yet.

In a Ubuntu 16.04 fresh install the Battery status for the mouse is showing up as unknown:

[image: Logitech mouse unknown]

This can be traced to the `upower --dump` configuration:

```
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/unknown_0003o046Do101Ax000B
  native-path:          /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.000A/0003:046D:101A.000B
  vendor:               Logitech, Inc.
  model:               
  serial:               6DB54BFE
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Sun 31 Dec 2017 01:59:27 PM MST (86 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       no
  unknown
    warning-level:       none
    icon-name:          'battery-missing-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1514753967  0.000   unknown
  History (rate):
    1514753967  0.000   unknown
```

I could only get this far after installing `solaar` because before that even "unknown" wasn't being displayed for the mouse.

On my older laptop which was upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 the battery status for the same wireless Mouse and Keyboard showed up fine when clicking on the systray's battery/power icon.

I've checked the `udev` rules in `/lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-csr.rules` as instructed in [bug fix](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=95260) and they look okay. I'm wondering if the rule is running too soon before USB is fully initialised in udev?

Any ideas how to begin fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Permanent Fix

I'm placing the permanent fix discovered a week later at the top of this answer because that is what people are likely most interested in.

Digging through old bug reports I found this related problem: [Logitech M515 does not work after upgrade to 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128345/logitech-m515-does-not-work-after-upgrade-to-12-04). Using solutions here I edited `/etc/rc.local` and inserted the following lines:

```
# Jan 05 2018 - Reload Logitech Unifying Receiver to get Mouse in Power Stats
modprobe -r hid_logitech_dj
modprobe    hid_logitech_dj
```

Then I rebooted **twice**. On the first reboot the external display didn't appear and the login prompt was delayed. On the second reboot everything was normal and the Power Statistics appeared as they should:

[image: Power stats normal]

## Temporary work-around

I found this [bug report](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=95260) which suggests unplugging and replugging the Unifying Receiver. Sure enough it worked:

[image: Logitech Mouse Work-around]

This bug report suggests running kernel >= 4.12 and `upower` >= 0.99.5. Although the current `upower` version is `0.99.7` it is unstable and the current version in Ubuntu is `0.99.4` released February 2016. It's not feasible to get a version >= `0.99.5`

### Login screen battery status

At the boot-up login screen the system tray displays the battery icon. Clicking on it reveals only the UPS and Laptop battery statistics.

### udev rules not running during boot only on replugging

This [bug report](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=154889) details how `udev` rules aren't running on boot but only when replugging cables. This "sounds" similar to the unifying receiver here. The bug report does provide clues on additional information to look for. ie `udev` (or something else) has enumerated devices in the system paths:

```
$ udevadm info /sys/class/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0005/0003:046D:2010.0007/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0005/0003:046D:2010.0007/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
E: POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY_LEVEL=High
E: POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=Logitech
E: POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=K800
E: POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=hidpp_battery_0
E: POWER_SUPPLY_ONLINE=1
E: POWER_SUPPLY_SCOPE=Device
E: POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER=2010-6d-b5-4b-fe
E: POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Discharging
E: SUBSYSTEM=power_supply

$ udevadm info /sys/class/power_supply/hidpp_battery_1
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0005/0003:046D:101A.0006/power_supply/hidpp_battery_1
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0005/0003:046D:101A.0006/power_supply/hidpp_battery_1
E: POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY_LEVEL=Normal
E: POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=Logitech
E: POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=Performance MX
E: POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=hidpp_battery_1
E: POWER_SUPPLY_ONLINE=1
E: POWER_SUPPLY_SCOPE=Device
E: POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER=101a-e6-ce-45-71
E: POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Discharging
E: SUBSYSTEM=power_supply
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** Even though `/sys/class/power...` contains information on Keyboard and Mouse batteries the Power Statistics display currently shows NOTHING, not even the keyboard anymore. After writing this paragraph I replugged the unifying receiver and the battery levels were displayed.

---

## June 13, 2020 update

Today neither keyboard nor mouse appear in Power Statistics. Also:

- `hidpp_battery_0` has changed to `hidpp_battery_1`
- `hidpp_battery_1` has changed to `hidpp_battery_4`

Googling for new information on the Power Statistics problem I discovered someone made a scrolling video of this **Ask Ubuntu** Q&A without credits or source:

- [Ubuntu: Logitech Performance MX mouse shows as "unknown" in Power Statistics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LbbbvFvfSu8)

It wasn't helpful watching a video slowing scrolling through what I already posted...

I did find this new link suggesting kernel > 4.7 and upower >= 0.99.5 fixes the problem:

- [Logitech MX Master (Unifying adapter) no power info](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/upower/upower/-/issues/39)

Comment: Unplugging and replugging also works well and from that moment on realtive lasting (without again unplugging) with my M705.

Comment: Have you tried using `solaar` it is a device manager for Logitech wireless devices. It is a better solution to the battery meter than having to unplug/plug. Some of the advanced settings can be accessed by `solaar-cli config -h`

Comment: @J.Starnes yes I've tried solaar. Only problem is it frequently asks for Unifying Receiver to be replugged too.

Comment: Intersting, On galliumOS and xubuntu 16.04 my m570, k520, m310, mk700 don't need to be unplug/plugged for proper batt meter.